# JSON schema - valid if object does *not* contain a particular property

Tags: json, jsonschema

Is it possible to set up a JSON schema that still allows for `additionalProperties` but does *not* match if a very particular property name is present? In other words, I need to know if it's possible to have the exact opposite of the `required` declaration.

Schema:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "x": { "type": "integer" }
    },
    "required": [ "x" ],
    "ban": [ "z" ] // possible?
}
```

Match:

```
{ "x": 123 }
```

Match:

```
{ "x": 123, "y": 456 }
```

Do *not* match:

```
{ "x": 123, "y": 456, "z": 789 }
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

What you want to do can be achieved using the `not` keyword.  If the `not` schema validates, the parent schema will not validate.

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "x": { "type": "integer" }
    },
    "required": [ "x" ],
    "not": { "required": [ "z" ] }
}
```

Comment: Not required does not mean "must not be present".

Comment: @jruizaranguren, are you trying to say this answer is wrong?  I can expand on my explanation if it is not clear why this schema answers the question.

Comment: You are right. I'm wrong. Not need to expand explanation.

Comment: While correct in JSON schema, I share @jruizaranguren's confusion about the logic. (Not the only place in JSON schema, sadly. :/)

Comment: I also think it's syntactically confusing (although it works to avoid the presence of the parameter). In the other hand, the validators I have used does not provides a clear error in such situations.

Comment: @adripanico - from when originally asked, wouldn't have worked, but with Draft 6+ a combination of "not": {"propertyNames": {"enum": ["bad", "properties"]}} works well with Validators, providing specific invalid property names in returned errors.

Comment: @JasonDesrosiers What jruizaranguren tries to imply is that `not required` means `even if it is there it doesn't matter`. That's not a problem with your answer, but the sense of the JSON schema syntax. `"not": { "required": [ "z" ] }` doesn't mean the same in natural english..

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to achieve something similar to what OP asked. I want to "ban" another property besides z. If I add it to the not required array: "not" : {"required" : ["z","y"]} and in the json body I sent only the properties x and z, it validates: Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: @jrf It's funny you ask that, because I just answered that question a couple hours ago and it's not a common question. The "What's up with `required`-`not` section should answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/61062869/1320693

Comment: Wow thanks @JasonDesrosiers! I've been looking about these topics in SO for quite a few days now, but haven't found much. That questions is exactly what I'm trying to do... I thought I was stretching the capabilities of json-schema too much, but I guess I'm not the only one! Thanks!

Answer (score 49):

There is a simpler approach. Define that if x is present it must not satisfy any schema. By reduction to absurdity x can not be present:

```
{
    "properties" : {
        "x" : {
            "not" : {}

        }
    }
}
```

**Update 2020/04/16**: As pointed out by @Carsten in a comment, from draft version 05 and above, the proposed schema can be simplified as follows:

```
{
    "properties": {
       "x": false
    }
}
```

Comment: The most convenient and non-confusing answer for me. The particular pro of it is that it is placed inside `properties` keyword, along with another properties.

Comment: IMO it's not an answer to this particular question, but it's really good.

Comment: A short-hand for `”x”: { ”not”: {} }` in newer draft versions would be `”x”: false`.

Comment: @kris_IV Why don't you think this answers the OP's question? This meets the criteria of "must not exist" precisely.

Comment: For anyone using it with AJV: if you want custom error messages with AJV validator for explaining why it is not allowed, then you cannot weave that into the shorthand syntax, but the classical "not" method works.

Comment: Works perfectly, with networknt, json-schema-validator however, gives a cryptic error '[Boolean schema false is not valid]'

Answer (score 6):

I solved the issue by banning additional properties via `"additionalProperties": false` but using `patternProperties` to allow any property name except the banned one.

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "x": { "type": "integer" }
    },
    "required": [ "x" ],
    "patternProperties": {
        "^(?!^z$).*": {}
    },
    "additionalProperties": false
}
```

Comment: Actually this should be the solution of the question. 

Answer (score 5):

To specify the absence of a field, you can expect it's type to be `null`.

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "x": { "type": "integer" },
        "z": { "type": "null" }

    },
    "required": [ "x" ]
}
```

Comment: Is 'null' the same as 'undefined', though?

Answer (score -2):

You can have type null for that particular property :

```
 z : {
"type": "null"
}
```

Comment: Works, however, with networknt jason-schema-validator, gives kind of ugly error: [$.<propert name>: array found, unknown expected]. But it is better than 'Boolean schema false is not valid '(refer: comment above)