# JSON Schema to require a value NOT be present

Tags: json, validation, jsonschema

I want to perform JSON validation on my schema, which has four properties:

- `group`
- `partition`
- `select`
- `features`

If using either `group` or `partition`, then `features` is required. If using `select`, then `features` is *prohibited*. (Note that this seems to be a different case than in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023536/how-do-i-require-one-field-or-another-or-one-of-two-others-but-not-all-of-them) - I don't want to make `features` 'not required', but make it so if you include it, it's a validation error.

So my three options are:

- `group` AND `features`
- `partition` AND `features`
- `select` AND NOT `features`

I've encoded these as:

```
"oneOf": [
  { "required": [ "group", "features" ] },
  { "required": [ "partition", "features" ] },
  { "required": [ "select" ] }
]
```

But I can't figure out how to appropriately force `features` to be excluded from the last option - or is this even a possibility?

Comment: you can define several schemas any of that valid, and place additionalProperties to false

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSON schema - valid if object does \*not\* contain a particular property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30515253/json-schema-valid-if-object-does-not-contain-a-particular-property)

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to model this. If you want to have the freedom to allow additional properties, while only explicitly excluding a property called "features", you can use the `not` keyword:

```
"oneOf": [
  { "required": [ "group", "features" ] },
  { "required": [ "partition", "features" ] },
  { "required": [ "select" ], "not": { "required": ["features"] } }
]
```

The `not` keyword evaluates as "valid" if the sub-schema is not valid, and evaluates to "invalid" if the sub-schema is valid.

Comment: At least within Visual Studio, using `not` in this way still lets me use both `select` and `features` together. I do want to be able to include other properties, but explicitly not `features`.

Comment: I am no expert, but using "not" with "required" like this does not prevent documents from containing "features" - it simply is not required that documents contain "features".

Comment: You misunderstand the spec. The not rule succeeds when the sub rule fails and vice versa. The required rule succeeds if the property exists and fails if it doesn't; not with required succeeds if the property is missing and fails if it exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can define several schemas any of that valid

```
   {
        "anyOf": [
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/group" },
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/partition" },
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/select" },
        ]
    }
```

and for select you can define schema with additionalProperties set to false, like so

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "select": {"type": "string"}
  },
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

Then you get error like this:

> ValidationError: Additional properties are not allowed

Comment: I am no expert, but the end of this section https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/combining.html#allof says that "additionalProperties" requires that "properties" is defined at the top level within the object, and does not work when "properties" is deep within an "anyOf". Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: By "item", did you mean "items" ? The OP doesn't talk about an array, so why is that there? Apologies if I'm just misunderstanding.

Comment: By item, I mean any named object, that we describe into schema, you can safely remove item wrapper if you describe single object.

Comment: Thanks! Also, I tried your solution out, and it's working for me, so clearly my first comment is misguided. Thanks for the answer! :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is a trick proposed in a non-accepted answer to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30515253/json-schema-valid-if-object-does-not-contain-a-particular-property), which involves the usage of `"not": {}`. That is, in case a property is present, can not satisfy any schema. Thus, it can not be present.

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "oneOf": [
        {
            "properties": {
                "group": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "features": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "group",
                "features"
            ]
        },
        {
            "properties": {
                "partition": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "features": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "partition",
                "features"
            ]
        },
        {
            "properties": {
                "select": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "features": {
                    "not": {}
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "select"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: @JonathanHartley. Right, Why? It solves the question.