# JSON schema any of a, b and/or c

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have the following schema, and what I am trying to accomplish, is where I can have one or more of the following:

- `a1` but not `a2` and vise versa
- `b1` but not `b2` and vise versa
- `c1` but not `c2` and vise versa

Here is the json schema that I am trying but it doesn't work:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "action": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "a1": {},
                "a2": {},
                "b1": {},
                "b2": {},
                "c1": {},
                "c2": {}    
            },
            "anyOf": [
                {
                    "oneOf": [
                        {"required": ["a1"]},
                        {"required": ["a2"]}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "oneOf": [
                        {"required": ["b1"]},
                        {"required": ["b2"]}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "oneOf": [
                        {"required": ["c1"]},
                        {"required": ["c2"]}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }                  
}
```

It is telling me that the following is valid json:

```
{
    "action": {
        "a1": {},
        "b1": {},
        "b2": {}
    }    
}
```

This shouldn't be valid because both `b1` and `b2` are set.

Comment: Can you explain what "doesn't work" about it?

Comment: I have updated my question with an example.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do it is with `dependencies`.  This says, if "a1" is present, then "a2" can not be present (etc. for b and c).

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "dependencies": {
    "a1": { "not": { "required": ["a2"] } },
    "b1": { "not": { "required": ["b2"] } },
    "c1": { "not": { "required": ["c2"] } }
  }
}
```

**EDIT: Full Schema**

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "action": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "a1": {},
                "a2": {},
                "b1": {},
                "b2": {},
                "c1": {},
                "c2": {}    
            },
            "dependencies": {
                "a1": { "not": { "required": ["a2"] } },
                "b1": { "not": { "required": ["b2"] } },
                "c1": { "not": { "required": ["c2"] } }
            }
        }
    }                  
}
```

Note that declaring properties in this case is meaningless because they are empty schemas.  I left it in to avoid confusion.

Comment: I have tried this, and I am not able to add `a1` and `a2`, but I can add `b1` and `b2`, I can also add `c1` and `c2`.

Comment: It works.  Either the validator you are working with has a bug or you didn't incorporate into your schema correctly.  I may have simplified too much and it wasn't clear where to put this.  I'll include the full schema just to make sure.

Comment: I do not think it is the editor. The schema allows for `a1` and `a2` to be present. Not required does not mean forbidden. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023536/json-schema-how-do-i-require-one-field-or-another-or-one-of-two-others-but-no

Comment: @jruizaranguren You are right that not-required doesn't mean forbidden, but you are wrong that this schema is incorrect.  But don't take my word for it; try it.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn This isn't the first time I've heard of Visual Studio having a bug in validating JSON Schemas.  I don't recall if it was this same issue or not.  It's possible that you will need to resort to a less elegant solution to work around the bug.